# TYPO3 - Failing to complete the Upgrade Wizard after upgrade from 7LTS to 8LTS - Error Out of memory

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

TYPO3 - I'm failing to complete the Upgrade Wizard after upgrade from 7LTS to 8LTS.

I have one step left:

Wizards available 96% Complete

Execute database migrations on single rows

Some row updaters have not been executed:
Migrate values in database records having "l10n_mode" either set to "exclude" or "mergeIfNotBlank"
Migrate values in sys_file_reference crop field
Scan for old "" syntax in richtext and text fields and update to ""

... but then I get an error:

Load extension configuration

The system detected a fatal error during script execution and redirected to this module. Your loaded extensions are now checked for possible problems. After incompatible extensions are unloaded, you can restart the initial action to proceed your request.
Detected Fatal Error
Out of memory (allocated 128270336) (tried to allocate 253974336 bytes) in /is/htdocs/host/www/typo3_src-8.7.6/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/Mysqli/MysqliStatement.php on line 172
Check for broken extensions

Checks whether the local extensions' ext_tables and ext_localconf files can be included without errors, meaning they can be loaded without breaking the system.
All local extensions can be loaded!

I already changed the values in .htacces ...

```
php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 240
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

... but with no success. How can I complete the upgrade wizard to 100%?

I have fairly large tables in two extension >500k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution would be to use the [TYPO3 console](https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console) which allows doing **all** upgrades either by once with the command line call `./typo3cms upgrade:all`.

Maybe you wanna also check the php.ini for CLI if there is enough memory assigned.